# inapp purchase inside extensions in iOS 8

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios8, ios-app-extension

Would it be possible to add inapp purchase inside extensions in iOS 8? 
For example, a custom keyboard may have free and pro versions based on inapp purchase.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should probably handle in-app purchases in the app itself, as the name suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom keyboard requires a container app anyhow, it would probably be a good idea to do it there. You could likely have UI on your keyboard interface to link to the app via `openURL:` directing users on how to purchase the "Pro" version. With that said, you can tell which APIs are not accessible if they are annotated with the `NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS` macro. You can see this on `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` as an example. If none of the StoreKit APIs you need to perform the purchase are marked as unavailable, it's likely that you'll be able to get it done within the extension.